How to vertical align a tspan element inside a text element in SVG
I've been trying to vertically align a tspan inside a span in SVG for a few hours now, with no success.
I've also tried using some suggestions from stackoverflow answers and questions with reference to dominant-baseline="middle" and alignment-baseline="middle", but nothing happened.
What I have currently done after some trial and error is this code here:


<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200" height="66"
  style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; user-select: none;">
    <rect width="200" height="66" x="0" y="0" fill="cyan"></rect>
    <g>
        <text class="t" x="30" y="30" xlink:space="preserve"
      style="font-size: 10px; font-family: monospace" fill="black"
      dominant-baseline="middle" alignment-baseline="middle">ISTRUE:
      <tspan class="tt" y="30" dominant-baseline="central" alignment-baseline="middle"
      fill="green" style="font-size: 20px;">YES</tspan></text>
    </g>
</svg>



At the end "ISTRUE:" class="t" has to be vertical aligned with "YES" class="tt" inside class="t".
They have a different font size and may also have a different family-font (for now it's monospace for both of them).

EDIT
I think I didn't express myself well. They need to be aligned on the same line vertically.
@Danny '365CSI' Engelman understood what I was trying to do, but using animations to align text seems a bit excessive. Your code is really nice to look at and thanks for your contribution, but I was looking for an easier way to put them vertically aligned on the same line.
Also (very importantly) inside the g tag there is a lot of other stuff that I didn't write with my own hands, so I can't use your animation for the svg.
Anyway I'll report the image of what you did in the snippet to make others understand what the result should be:

I also tried to set the y equal for both classes, but it's still missing a few pixels for it to be in line (looking by eye).

Are you certain they aren't vertically aligned - but that they happen not to use any characters with descenders so there appears to be a bit of extra space underneath where descenders would go?

You can get close to the desired alignment via dominant-baseline="central" which aligns text ~ around the center of the capital letter height.
Update: While Firefox and Chromium inherit the dominant-baseline from <text> to <tspan> – in Webkit/safari you need to apply this attribute to tspans as well.
However, depending on the font the result may not be exactly what you want.
But you can tweak the alignment by adding dy offsets with relative units (like % or em). In other words the browser doesn't really know the visual vertical center or the tight bounding box of the rendered text. All alignment is based on mertic values retrieved from the parsed font's data tables.


<h3>No baseline adjustment</h3>
<svg  viewBox="0 0 200 66">
    <rect width="200" height="66" x="0" y="0" fill="cyan" />
    <g>
      <line x1="0" y1="30" x2="100%" y2="30" stroke="red" stroke-width="0.5" />
      <rect width="100%" height="20" x="0" y="20" fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="0.5" />
      <rect width="100%" height="10" x="0" y="25" fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="0.5" />

      <text class="t" x="30" y="30"
      style="font-size: 10px; font-family: monospace"
      dominant-baseline="central">ISTRUE:
      <tspan class="tt" 
      fill="green" dominant-baseline="central" style="font-size: 20px;" >YES</tspan>
      <tspan class="ttt" 
      fill="green" dominant-baseline="central" style="font-size: 36px;" >YES</tspan>
      </text>
    </g>
</svg>

<h3>Baseline adjustment via dy</h3>

<svg  viewBox="0 0 200 66">
    <rect width="200" height="66" x="0" y="0" fill="cyan" />
    <g>
      <line x1="0" y1="30" x2="100%" y2="30" stroke="red" stroke-width="0.5" />
      <rect width="100%" height="20" x="0" y="20" fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="0.5" />
      <rect width="100%" height="10" x="0" y="25" fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="0.5" />

      <text class="t" x="30" y="30"
      style="font-size: 10px; font-family: monospace"
      dominant-baseline="central" >ISTRUE:
      <tspan class="tt" 
      fill="green" dominant-baseline="central" style="font-size: 20px;" dy="-0.015em">YES</tspan>
      <tspan class="ttt" 
      fill="green" dominant-baseline="central" style="font-size: 36px;" dy="-0.015em">YES</tspan>
      </text>
    </g>
</svg>



Unfortunately, you can't change the dy baseline offsets in CSS as dy is currently not a presentation attribute. The best you can do is to specify a font via @font-face for a consistent rendering. But you'll need to find suitable dy offsets for your font family - there is no one-fits-all solution.


/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Exo';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/exo/v21/4UaZrEtFpBI4f1ZSIK9d4LjJ4lM3OwRmOw.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+0304, U+0308, U+0329, U+2000-206F, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}


.exo{
  font-family: 'Exo';
}
<h3>Baseline adjustment via dy for Exo font</h3>

<svg  viewBox="0 0 200 66" class="exo">
    <rect width="200" height="66" x="0" y="0" fill="cyan" />
    <g>
      <line x1="0" y1="30" x2="100%" y2="30" stroke="red" stroke-width="0.5" />
      <rect width="100%" height="20" x="0" y="20" fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="0.5" />
      <rect width="100%" height="10" x="0" y="25" fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="0.5" />

      <text class="t" x="30" y="30"
      style="font-size: 10px;"
      dominant-baseline="central" dy="0.03em" >ISTRUE:
      <tspan class="tt" 
      fill="green" dominant-baseline="central" style="font-size: 20px;" dy="0.01em">YES</tspan>
      <tspan class="ttt" 
      fill="green" dominant-baseline="central" style="font-size: 36px;" dy="0.01em">YES</tspan>
      </text>
    </g>
</svg>




So something so simple is actually very difficult.
Not only because the browser "doesn't really know the visual vertical center or the tight bounding box", but also because Firefox, Safari, Chrome (Chromium) work differently on dominant-baseline.
And probably what I want to do can't be done unless I set a standard character for the font used in the text.

However if I declare more fonts, for example font-family: Exo, sans-serif, Arial; I will never know if it is aligned.

Apart from the fact SVG's text capabilities definitely suck – this is not specific to SVG and you'll encounter the same problems in HTML. Fonts just don't have a vertical center. What would it be for capital text only or a text with ascenders and descenders (e.g "Äg").  Imagine how difficult the alignment would be if font rendering was based on the actual bounding box - baseline alignment is the only sane concept. The best you can do is to choose fonts with similar cap heights so the generic centering makes sense.

This answer is the closest thing to what the answer to the question should be.

QUOTING: Ultimately the font inside HTML and SVG "sucks" . But if I chose the same font for both would I be sure it was vertically aligned? P.S. I gave you an up on the answer as well as Danny '365CSI' Engelman. You'll see when the score is high enough.

U THE BEST ONE. Lucky whoever reads your detailed explanation

If you add x and y values ​​to the tt class, it can be aligned vertically. You can see it in the code below. You can edit the spaces as you wish.


<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200" height="66"
  style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; user-select: none;">
    <rect width="200" height="66" x="0" y="0" fill="cyan"></rect>
    <g>
        <text class="t" x="30" y="30" xlink:space="preserve"
      style="font-size: 10px; font-family: monospace" fill="black"
      dominant-baseline="middle" alignment-baseline="middle">ISTRUE:
      <tspan class="tt" x="30" y="50" dominant-baseline="central" alignment-baseline="middle"
      fill="green" style="font-size: 20px;">YES</tspan></text>
    </g>
</svg>




@ Mustafa They are aligned exactly the opposite of how I wanted them to be! Anyway, thanks for your input.

You can do without any x y positioning, by animating the text over a path

visibility code to prevent a FOUC
animateMotion set `to dur=".001s" to display "immediatly"
(text is displayed at 0,0 first)
keypoints="0.5,0.5" to animate to halfway the path
to be precise: the <g> is animated, not the <text>
set the path stroke to transparent to hide it
or rename the attribute stroke to no-stroke (not a SVG attribute!)



<svg width="400" viewBox="0 0 200 66" style="background:cyan">
  <style>
    .true { font:15px monospace; fill:black }
    .yes  { font:30px Arial;     fill:green }
  </style>
  <path id="guide" d="M40 0v66" stroke="red"/>
  <path d="M0 33h200" stroke="blue"/>
  <g dominant-baseline="central" visibility="hidden">
    <set attributeName="visibility" from="hidden" to="visible" begin=".01s" />    
    <animateMotion path="M40 0v66" dur=".001s" fill="freeze" keyPoints=".5;.5" keyTimes="0;1" calcMode="linear"/>
    <text class="true">ISTRUE:</text>
    <text class="yes" dx="2em">YES</text>
  </g>
</svg>



Note
Because that id="guide" is a global ID
You are going to run into trouble when you add multiple SVGs to the page.
That first ID will always be used by all SVGs using that guide.
Easily avoided by wrapping your SVG in declarative shadowDOM
side-effect: now global CSS can not style the SVG
<svg-protected> can be any name you want (with a hyphen so it is created as a native Custom Element/Web Component)


<svg-protected>
  <template shadowrootmode="open">
    <svg width="300" viewBox="0 0 200 66" style="background:gold">
      <style>
        .true{font:15px monospace;fill:black} .yes{font:30px Arial;fill:green}
      </style>
      <path id="guide" d="M40 0v66" stroke="red"/>
      <g dominant-baseline="central" visibility="hidden">
        <set attributeName="visibility" from="hidden" to="visible" begin=".01s" />    
        <animateMotion dur=".001s" fill="freeze" keyPoints=".5;.5" keyTimes="0;1" calcMode="linear">
          <mpath href="#guide"/>
        </animateMotion>
        <text class="true">ISTRUE:</text><text class="yes" dx="2em">YES</text>
      </g>
    </svg>
  </template>  
</svg-protected>
<svg-protected>
  <template shadowrootmode="open">
    <svg width="300" viewBox="0 0 200 66" style="background:beige">
      <style>
        .true{font:15px monospace;fill:red} .yes{font:30px Arial;fill:gold }
      </style>
      <path id="guide" d="M60 0v66" stroke="red"/>
      <g dominant-baseline="central" visibility="hidden">
        <set attributeName="visibility" from="hidden" to="visible" begin=".01s" />    
        <animateMotion dur=".001s" fill="freeze" keyPoints=".5;.5" keyTimes="0;1" calcMode="linear">
          <mpath href="#guide"/>
        </animateMotion>
        <text class="true">ISTRUE:</text><text class="yes" dx="2em">YES</text>
      </g>
    </svg>
  </template>  
</svg-protected>



